# R Shiny: How to catch error: argument of length zero

Tags: r, shiny

I have an `if` statement:

```
if(
  length(input$File2)== 0 |
    length(input$File1)== 0 |
    is.null(input$File1) |
    is.null(input$File2) |
    is.null(input$Desk) |
    is.null(input$StrikeRange)
  ){
  ....do something 
}
```

and I am getting this error:

```
 Error in if (length(input$File2) == 0 |
                length(input$File1) == 0 ) argument is of length zero
```

I think one of the arguments here has length zero. How do I make the `if` statement below return `NULL` if one of the arguments has length zero?

Comment: Have you tried checking each of the conditions in your if statement to find out which one is throwing the error? Maybe one of the input files is `NULL`, for example.

Comment: Usually error messages end where the error occurred, so I would check `length(input$File1)` and `dim(input$File1)` first

Comment: Maybe try rearranging the order, but if is.null() is true you are going to get that error with those comparisons.